# one input file to yield many output files

Tags: slurm, snakemake

This is a bit of a backwards approach to snakemake whose main paradigm is "one job -> one output", but i need many reruns in parallel of my script on the same input matrix on the slurm batch job submission cluster. How do I achieve that?

I tried specifying multiple threads, multiple nodes, each time indicating one cpu per task, but it never submits an array of many jobs, just an array of one job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a nice way to submit an array job like that.  In snakemake, you need to specify a unique output for each job.  But you can have the same input.  If you want 1000 runs of a job:

```
ids = range(1000)
rule all:
    input: expand('output_{sample}_{id}', sample=samples, id=ids)

rule simulation:
    input: 'input_{sample}'
    output: 'output_{sample}_{id}'
    shell: echo {input} > {output}
```

If that doesn't help, provide more information about the rule/job you are trying to run.